# cs-cart 4.22 - product import

Tags: php, csv, cs-cart

I'm attempting to upload products using a CSV, but a few things are not working as properly.

1. The product images are not being uploaded at all, The csv field for 'Image detail' has only the name of the file, without anything else, and all the images are uploaded to var/exim/backup/images, Am I missing something?
2. My stock is managed using product combination, Each combination is a mixture of size and color, However the "combination" field, that's required by CS-cart, is no where to be found manually, only after adding a combination **by hand** and then checking the database, is the combination field avaiable, that means I cannot use the csv method unless I have a complete table of `long product code` to `actual sizes and colors`. Just for reference, this is my `combination` field in the database for one given combination : `383_1473_459_1701`, this is for `mediu, green`. - How can I upload combinations using CSV without knowing the combination field?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should inform you that starting from CS-Cart or Multi-Vendor version **4.1.1** images can be imported only from the `/path/to/cart/var/files/` directory. So you should move all your images to the `var/files/1 directory` (or its any subdirectory) and correct the path in the Images directory field on the **Administration > Import data > Products > Images page** in your store admin panel.

For example, if you move your files to the `var/files/1/images` directory, you should specify images in the Images directory field. Please check it.

I know its quite confusing but I've managed to find out by looking into [their forums](http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/35409-import-images-not-working-in-cs-cart-mv413/page__view__findpost__p__181143) and seeing that you must put your image files to: **/public_html/var/files/1/exim/backup/images/**

Comment: I've figured this exact thing out a few days ago, Ofcourse this is not documented anywhere. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer 1: You need to manually upload the images from the old directory to the new directory. (when you are importing the products, there is an image url, that is the folder you must put your images, using ftp, etc.)